# Spring transaction rollback for only erroneous objects and hide stacktrace for it

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have 100 objects and I want save it to DB.

```
@Service
public class TestService {

  private final TestDao testDao;

  public TestService(TestDao testDao) {
    this.testDao = testDao;
  }

  @Transactional
  public void saveTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      Test test = new Test();
      if (i == 10 || i == 20) {
        test.setName("123");
      } else {
        test.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      }
      testDao.save(test);
    }
  }
}
```

I have uniq constraint on name column and if I try save 2 objects with some name - I get exception.

I need save 99 objects(uniw names) and skip 1 object with dublicate name. But if I try insert dublicate I get Ecxeption and transaction rollback all objects. I change my dao savee() methos:

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
public class TestDao {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void save(Test test) {
    entityManager.persist(test);
  }
}
```

Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW - start internal transaction on each object and rollbak only dublicate object. It vork fine. But in log print this exception stacktrace/ How can I hide this stacktace?

Comment: By catching the exception and not writing it to the log file?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a logging filter for your logging framework (for example, [Logback Filter](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html)).

Imho, this would be a hack and what you should do is validate your objects before you save them.

This way, you can be sure that the whole "batch" can be committed.